# "Unclosed expression sequence" error in VimScript

Tags: vim, macvim

I have the following in order to set my `statusline`:

```
set stl=%<\ [Buf:\ %n]%m\ %f\ [
set stl+=%{empty(&filetype) ? \"" : \"," . toupper(&filetype) . \", \"}
set stl+=%{(&fenc!=''?&fenc:&enc)}]

set stl+=%=[0x\%02.2B]\ [Line:\ %04l/%04L\ \|\ Col:\ %c%V]\ (%P)
```

I personally don't see anything wrong with it, but it just keeps giving me the following error:
`E540: Unclosed expression sequence: stl+=%{empty(&filetype)`

Does anybody know what this error means? I've been forever trying to solve it, but I just can't understand what it means.

Thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: It looks like you'll need to do that logic in a function: `statusline` doesn't seem to like your ternary conditional. Also what's wrong with `%Y`?

Comment: It's because sometimes it has a filetype, and sometimes it doesn't, and if it doesn't then there's only a comma and a space, so it looks strange, so I wanted to check and show different results depending if it is defined or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `:set`, all spaces in the value must be escaped with a backslash, too. Therefore, it's recommended to do away with any unnecessary whitespace there, or use `:let &stl = '...'` instead (where only contained `'` characters must be doubled).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve it. :) Also, thanks for my other question. ;)

Comment: @Eduan One addition: `set stl+='…'` has `let &stl.='…'` (note: dot, not plus) rough equivalent (rough because it works for `stl`, but for e.g. runtimepath option equivalent would be different).

Comment: @ZyX Thanks! Yes I saw that in Ingo's answer to my previous question, still, thanks. :)